# Scope inside array sort method

Tags: javascript

Can please anyone explain what is going on here?

```
['A', 'B', 'C'].sort(function(a,b) {
    console.log(this); // this ---> Window
});

['A', 'B', 'C'].sort.bind(['A', 'B', 'C'], function(a,b) {
    console.log(this); // this ---> Window
})();
```

I would expect 'this' to point to my array but for some reason it points to the Window object.

Comment: You are binding to `sort` not to the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
['A', 'B', 'C'].sort(function(a,b) {
    console.log(this);
}.bind(['A','B','C']));
```